# Failing to send protobuf stream over a named pipe and getting result back

Tags: c#, .net-core, named-pipes, protobuf-net

I have having troubles sending objects back and forth (duplex communication) using named pipes. The code:

Dto:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ServerResponse
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ServerRequest
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Server:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting Server");
    StartServer();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop server..");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void StartServer()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var server = new NamedPipeServerStream("MyPipes");

        server.WaitForConnection();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");

        //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server);
        //StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(server);
        while (true)
        {
            //string line = reader.ReadLine();
            //Console.WriteLine(line);
            //writer.WriteLine(line.ToUpper());
            //writer.Flush();

            var request = Serializer.Deserialize<ServerRequest>(server);
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {request.Name}, Age: {request.Age}");

            var response = new ServerResponse() { FirstName = request.Name, LastName = "Always this name!" };
            Serializer.Serialize(server, response);
            server.Flush();
        }
    });
}
```

Client:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Client");

    var client = new NamedPipeClientStream("MyPipes");
    client.Connect();

    //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client);
    //StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client);
    while (true)
    {
        //string input = Console.ReadLine();
        //if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) break;
        //writer.WriteLine(input);
        //writer.Flush();
        //Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());

        string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
        var request = new ServerRequest() { Name = firstName, Age = firstName.Length };
        Serializer.Serialize(client, request);
        client.Flush();

        var response = Serializer.Deserialize<ServerResponse>(client);
        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {response.FirstName}, Age: {response.LastName}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

It works just fine, when sending a single line of `string`, but the `protobuf` fails on me.

For some reason, `Deserialize` method seems to never stop reading data from stream, therefore I am never able to decode the incoding server request. But if the client is forcefully stopped, then the request gets received.

I also tried using `SteamWriter` and `StreamReader` to no avail.. Is it possible to transmit protobuf objects in duplex communication? I would appreciate if somebody would point out what I am doing wrong..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

protobuf is not a self-terminating data format; you need to use some kind of framing. Fortunately, the library includes a few basic implementations for your convenience, so : if you use `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` and `DeserializeWithLengthPrefix` (making sure to use the same configuration on both sides): it should work.

Without framing: the nature of protobuf is "read until the end of the stream", i.e. exactly what you're seeing. The reason for this is that protobuf is desiged to be concatenatable (is that a word?) **even for single messages**.