# Unable to establish two way communications using named pipes and Protobuf in .NET

Tags: .net, f#, named-pipes, protobuf-net

Starting from https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/IPC-in-net-core-using-protobuf/, I am trying to establish a two-way communication.
I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616643/failing-to-send-protobuf-stream-over-a-named-pipe-and-getting-result-back) SO post on the subject, but still I cannot make it work.
Below the server and client code (in F#)

```
// Server
open System.IO.Pipes
open ProtoBuf

    let pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("MyPipe", PipeDirection.InOut)        
    pipe.WaitForConnection()
    let request = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<string>(pipe, PrefixStyle.Fixed32)
    Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(pipe, "response", PrefixStyle.Fixed32)
    pipe.Flush()
    pipe.WaitForPipeDrain()
    pipe.Dispose()
```

```
//Client
open System.IO.Pipes
open ProtoBuf

    let pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "MyPipe", PipeDirection.InOut)
    pipe.Connect()
    Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(pipe, "request", PrefixStyle.Fixed32)
    pipe.Flush()
    pipe.WaitForPipeDrain()
    let response = DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<string>(pipe, PrefixStyle.Fixed32)
    pipe.Dispose()
```

This is what happens:

1. Start the server. It blocks in *pipe.WaitForConnection*.
2. Start the client. Connection succeeds and the code blocks at *Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix*.
3. As a consequence of 2, server resumes and calls *Serialize.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix*, which does not return.

Now both processes are deadlocked.

4. Kill the client.
5. The server resumes and the DeserializeWithLengthPrefix returns null in request.

What can I do to avoid the deadlock and make the workflow run as expected?

Comment: [PipeTransmissionMode.Message: How do .NET named pipes distinguish between messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4514784/3744182) and  [Creating a Server Using Named Pipes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/864679/Creating-a-Server-Using-Named-Pipes) may be relevant.  You may need to use `PipeTransmissionMode.Message`.

Comment: @dbc I tried setting PipeTransmissionMode.Message. No difference unfortunately

Comment: The code you've posted works on my machine, although I had to fix some compiler errors first. Are you sure you're executing exactly the same code?

Comment: @BrianBerns the code is the same however the context is probably different: server is running as a .NET Framework 4.8 process, client as an Excel .xll AddIn (Excel-DNA).

Comment: Try to create pipes with PipeOptions.Asynchronous. If grpc uses async methods under the hood, it could lead to deadlocks